# How to configure a non-embedded hasMany relationship with breeze.js

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to configure a few models with breeze.js

The first is session and I was able to get this working perfectly with a simple query like the below

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("sessions").toType("Session");
```

..but when I tried to add a related "speakers" array to the session I seem to be left with an empty array after the materialization step is complete

Do I need to write a custom json adapter for an api that looks like this?

```
/api/sessions/

[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "javascript", 
        "speakers": [
            1
        ]
    }
]

/api/speakers/1/

{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Toran", 
    "session": 1
}
```

Here is my current model configuration (mostly working)

```
var ds = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: 'api',
    hasServerMetadata: false,
    useJsonp: false
});
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
this.instance = new breeze.EntityManager({dataService: ds});
this.instance.metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "Speaker",
    namespace: "App",
    dataProperties: {
        id: { dataType: "Int64", isPartOfKey: true },
        name: { dataType: "String" },
        session: { dataType: "Int64" }
    },
    navigationProperties: {
        session: {
            entityTypeName: "Session", isScalar: true,
            associationName: "session", foreignKeyNames: ["session"]
        }
    }
});
this.instance.metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "Session",
    namespace: "App",
    dataProperties: {
        id: { dataType: "Int64", isPartOfKey: true },
        name: { dataType: "String" },
        speakers: { dataType: "Undefined" }
    },
    navigationProperties: {
        speakers: {
            entityTypeName: "Speaker", isScalar: false,
            associationName: "speakers", foreignKeyNames: ["speakers"]
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help !

note** I'm using ember.js (not backbone/ko/angular)

I tried to keep the above brief but if you need absolutely everything, checkout this single js file

https://github.com/toranb/embereeze/blob/master/website/static/website/js/app.js

**update**

if I remove the "speakers" dataProperty breeze gets fairly unhappy in this block of code (as it's not a dataProperty on the session model)

```
var fkProps = fkNames.map(function (fkName) {
    //fkName is speakers .... yet it's not a data property so bad things happen :(
    return parentEntityType.getDataProperty(fkName);
});
var fkPropCollection = parentEntityType.foreignKeyProperties;
// Array.prototype.push.apply(parentEntityType.foreignKeyProperties, fkProps);

fkProps.forEach(function (dp) {
```

Comment: Remove the dataProperty speakers and leave the navigation property and give the session on speak an id for the foreign key property but leave the navigation property as is

Comment: the first part -done. the session: { dataType: "Int64" } part is how the api looks (the FK is actually just session) unless I missed something I'm not sure how to modify that dataProperty (on the speaker) to wire this up correctly (thanks again)

Comment: Rename the navigation property something else then to allow the association - you could intercept it with a jsinresultsadapter but that is a bit overkill

Comment: updated to show my error after removing "speakers" dataProperty from the session model

Comment: It looks like this is where the backbone model store sets up an empty array for something like this. The ember array doesn't do that so maybe I need to override the init and do something like this breeze.makeRelationArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a PR - the association name should be the same on both ends, much like any relational database would have.

```
this.instance.metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "Speaker",
    namespace: "App",
    dataProperties: {
        id: { dataType: "Int64", isPartOfKey: true },
        name: { dataType: "String" },
        session: { dataType: "Int64" }
    },
    navigationProperties: {
        sessionModel: {
            entityTypeName: "Session", isScalar: true,
            associationName: "Speaker_Sessions", foreignKeyNames: ["session"]
        }
    }
});
this.instance.metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "Session",
    namespace: "App",
    dataProperties: {
        id: { dataType: "Int64", isPartOfKey: true },
        name: { dataType: "String" }
    },
    navigationProperties: {
        speakers: {
            entityTypeName: "Speaker", isScalar: false,
            associationName: "Speaker_Sessions"
        }
    }
});
```

So I renamed the association, removed the extra `speakers` property on the Session (there is no property for the relationship, simply an inverse that should be mapped) and then removed the foreign key on the session as you don't need one there.  By assigning passing `session` down from the API with the models shown above should be enough to let Breeze know

1. Speakers' have a session property, which is a foreign key pointing to a single session.
2. Sessions have a collection of speakers, which should be mapped on the *other* end

Comment: FWIW, this approach facilitates a 1-M association between Session and Speaker. But what if a Speaker gives several talks? You really need a m-to-m ... which Breeze expects to involve an intermediate linking/mapping entity. Torban's original design embedded the linking information in the Session as a collection of FKs to Speaker. This is clearly non-relational and Breeze doesn't know how to maintain navigation paths that are built that way. But it might make sense and I'm curious about whether this design is popular. In any case, it doesn't seem like an Ember issue per se.